# django test case with dynamic model structure

Tags: django

Am working on a django package which is based on configurations it will add relations, for example

```
@receiver(class_prepared, dispatch_uid='add_store_fields')
def add_store_fields(sender, **kwargs):
    """ add_store_fields
    """
    if sender.__name__ == 'Store':
        # allowing multiple stores in installation
        if settings.SHOPLER_STORE_FOREIGN_KEY:
            field = models.ForeignKey(settings.SHOPLER_STORE_FOREIGN_KEY)
            field.contribute_to_class(sender, "store_owner")
```

Am trying to build test case for this, so I would run the test cases when the SHOPLER_STORE_FOREIGN_KEY is specified and when it is not. For that, I did the following

```
class SingleStoreModeTestCase(TestCase):
    """ SingleStoreModeTestCase
    single store mode is tests performed when store is singular by design
    """
    def setUp(self):
        """ setup """

    @override_settings(SHOPLER_STORE_FOREIGN_KEY=None)
    def test_forieng_key_installed_correctly(self):
        """ test_forieng_key_installed_correctly
        """
        print hasattr(Store, 'store_owner')
        self.assertEqual(1, 1, '')


class MultiStoreModeTestCase(TestCase):
    """ MultiStoreModeTestCase
    single store mode is tests performed when store is singular by design
    """
    def setUp(self):
        """ setup """

    @override_settings(SHOPLER_STORE_FOREIGN_KEY=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def test_forieng_key_installed_correctly(self):
        """ test_forieng_key_installed_correctly
        """
        print hasattr(Store, 'store_owner')
        self.assertEqual(1, 1, '')
```

the problem am facing, is that override_settings is only passing it to the function so the initiation of the schema happens at an earlier step. How can I force the schema to rebuild on each test case with the settings override? anyone can advise?

Thanks,

Comment: I also just tried django-nose with rebuild_schema in the parameter and it didn't work

Comment: You could try instantiating Store in setUp